# SUM of SUMPRODUCTs - Formula is too long?

Tags: sum, excel-formula, product

I just tried running an admittedly long formula and Excel came back to tell me it's too long. Currently I am using SUM on a number (probably 30-40) of SUMPRODUCT formulas.

A bit of background about it:
I am trying to match the origin and destination of a product, so I created a new sheet (Sheet 2) with every country in the world listed down Column 1 and across Row 1. The SUMPRODUCT formula I wrote goes into Sheet 1, where there are number of columns containing origin and destination of various products. The rows are based on each organization, so one organization may have 13 products with different countries of origin and multiple destinations per product.

The SUMPRODUCT formula I'm using looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((BA2:BA501="NO")*(P2:P501="Guatemala")*(R2:R501="Guatemala")*(S2:S501)
```

P = the country of origin

R = the country of destination

S = the volume to be summed

BA = in some cases, I have the actual distribution of the product, so the "destination" volume should not be included. So, it should only use the destination if BA=0

I had to identify the various columns by hand, resulting in a truly horrendous length of SUMPRODUCTS, which I then used SUM(Sumproduct 1, 2, 3...) around to get the total amount of products matching a COUNTRY origin/destination in the matrix on Sheet 2.

So after going through all this work, I'm a bit upset that Excel is saying it's too long! Does anyone know if there is a way to circumvent this, or if there's some solution I'm overlooking?

Thanks!

p.s. I doubt anyone is interested in reading this, but here's the full formula that Excel rejected:

```
=SUM(SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$R$2:$R$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$S$2:$S$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$T$2:$T$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$U$2:$U$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$V$2:$V$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$W$2:$W$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$X$2:$X$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$Y$2:$Y$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$Z$2:$Z$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AA$2:$AA$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AB$2:$AB$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AC$2:$AC$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="YES")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$P$2:$P$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AX$2:$AX$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!CE$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AZ$2:$AZ$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AE$2:$AE$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AG$2:$AG$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AH$2:$AH$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AE$2:$AE$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AI$2:$AI$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AJ$2:$AJ$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AE$2:$AE$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AK$2:$AK$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AL$2:$AL$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AE$2:$AE$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AM$2:$AM$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AN$2:$AN$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BA$2:$BA$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AE$2:$AE$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AO$2:$AO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$AP$2:$AP$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BF$2:$BF$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BG$2:$BG$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BH$2:$BH$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BI$2:$BI$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BJ$2:$BJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BK$2:$BK$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BL$2:$BL$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BM$2:$BM$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BN$2:$BN$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BO$2:$BO$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BP$2:$BP$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BQ$2:$BQ$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BV$2:$BV$501="YES")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BD$2:$BD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BS$2:$BS$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BU$2:$BU$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CA$2:$CA501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CB$2:$CB$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CC$2:$CC501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CD$2:$CD$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CE$2:$CE501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CF$2:$CF$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CG$2:$CG501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CH$2:$CH$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CI$2:$CI501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CJ$2:$CJ$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CK$2:$CK501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CL$2:$CL$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CQ$2:$CQ$501="YES")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$BY$2:$BY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CN$2:$CN501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CP$2:$CP$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CV$2:$CV$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CW$2:$CW$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CX$2:$CX$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CY$2:$CY$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CZ$2:$CZ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DA$2:$DA$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DB$2:$DB$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DC$2:$DC$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DD$2:$DD$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DE$2:$DE$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DF$2:$DF$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DG$2:$DG$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DL$2:$DL$501="YES")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$CT$2:$CT$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DI$2:$DI$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DK$2:$DK$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DQ$2:$DQ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DR$2:$DR$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DS$2:$DS$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DT$2:$DT$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DU$2:$DU$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DV$2:$DV$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DW$2:$DW$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DX$2:$DX$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DY$2:$DY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DZ$2:$DZ$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EA$2:$EA$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EB$2:$EB$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EG$2:$EG$501="YES")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$DO2:$DO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$ED$2:$ED$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EF$2:$EF$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EL$2:$EL$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EM$2:$EM$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EN$2:$EN$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EO$2:$EO$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EP$2:$EP$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EQ$2:$EQ$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$ER$2:$ER$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$ES$2:$ES$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$ET$2:$ET$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EU$2:$EU$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="NO")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EV$2:$EV$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EW$2:$EW$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FB$2:$FB$501="YES")*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EJ2:$EJ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$EY$2:$EY$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FA$2:$FA$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FE2:$FE$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FG$2:$FG$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FI$2:$FI$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FL2:$FL$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FN$2:$FN$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FP$2:$FP$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FS2:$FS$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FU$2:$FU$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FW$2:$FW$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$FZ2:$FZ$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GB$2:$GB$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GD$2:$GD$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GG2:$GG$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GI$2:$GI$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GK$2:$GK$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GN2:$GN$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GP$2:$GP$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GR$2:$GR$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GU2:$GU$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GW$2:$GW$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$GY$2:$GY$501)),SUMPRODUCT(('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$IL2:$IL$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!$B124)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$IO$2:$IO$501='THE FLOW OF COOKSTOVES -WI ORG'!EC$2)*('IN BETWEEN, ALL'!$IR$2:$IR$501)))
```

Comment: There is a limit on the length of a formula of 8192 characters (Excel 2010, smaller in previous versions). [See here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=1)

Comment: If you shorten your sheet names, it will fit.  That said, I'd seriously think about redesigning your sheet.  There _must_ be a better way than this...

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized there's a limit. Yeah, it's definitely not the best format but I'm on a time crunch and just decided to go with what I have... I'm thinking that I might break it up - use only the first half of the formulas in one sheet and other in a second sheet, and then sum across sheets.

Comment: That would do it, and splitting it up would give you a fighting change at maintaining it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your criterias are ever the same and only the range to be summed changes, then you could use the SUMPRODUCT in this way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((BA2:BA501="NO")*(P2:P501="Guatemala")*(R2:R501="Guatemala"),
S2:S501+T2:T501+V2:V501+AA2:AA501)
```

Greetings

Axel